# Vascularization, good or bad for health/muscle growth

Tags: muscle, venous-system, weightlifting, bloated-bloating

I have recently started at the gym and noticed an excessively flow of blood and bloated veins on my arm when I exercise them...I googled it...it says that is called vascularization but just that...and other uninteresting info about bodybuilding...

I would like to know if that is healthy or at least good for muscle growth or what